# How to make a query from a query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I did this query to filter data from rif

```
$incidencias2 = DB::table('incidencias')
->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(rif)'));
```

And I would like use this information that I obtained from the first query to filter the data from rif in this query:

```
$av2 = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(cat_cliente) as av2'), 'cat_cliente')
    ->whereIn('cat_cliente', ['AV'])
    ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
    ->get();
```

How could I do that? can somebody help me?

Comment: Where you do want to use the information in your second query?

Comment: because I used a Distinct for rif to filter the repeated data, and I don't know how to use the distinct only for rif in the second query.. I tried all

Comment: I only want to filter the repeated data from the column rif that's why I used a Distinct in rif in the first query

Comment: But you are only retrieving the count in the first query.

Comment: yeah.. only the count

Comment: All that I want to do is filter the repeated data from rif in the first count and join that to the second query... because I don't want repeated rif's in my second query.. any suggestion for that?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the count of related rows from `clientes_incid` in your seond query?

Comment: yes!! I'm trying to get the count from cat_cliente which is a column from the table clientes_incid

Comment: I got the count with that query... but I need to filter the repeated data of rif.. that's why I filtered with a distinct the repeated data of rif in the first query

Comment: @Rwd Any suggestion?